# NaN answer is coming i dont know why ...?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make the total of checkbox on check here is my script

```
echo "<input type=checkbox value=$printing->id name=ship[] onclick=UpdateCost($netwt);>"
```

```
function UpdateCost(elem){  
    if(isNaN(total)){
        total = 0;
    }
    if(elem.checked == true){ 
        total += Number(elem.value); 
    } else {
        total -=Number(elem.value);
    }

    alert(total);
    document.getElementById('total').value = total.toFixed(0);
}
```

Comment: which language is that? add all the appropriate tags

Comment: @phuclv this is js

Comment: what's the output ? can you please log "elem.value" in UpdateCost function and check what's the value.  In addition to that instead of using isNaN , can you use Number.isNaN ,because NaN will not check for the type

Comment: its php and js . checkbox is in for loop and I am trying to make the total of net weight

Comment: I see `isNaN(total)` at the start of your function body, but I don't see where `total` is declared.  Is this a typo?  Is `total` a declared variable with a global scope?  Why aren't you quote-wrapping your html attribute values? What are the values for `$printing->id` and `$netwt`?  This is not a great question title.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made some minor changes to code you've provided see below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function UpdateCost(elem)
{  
    alert(elem.value);
    let total = Number(elem.value);
    if(isNaN(total)){
        total = 0;
    }
    if(elem.checked === true){ 
        total += Number(elem.value); 
    } else {
        total -= Number(elem.value);
    }

    alert(total);
    document.getElementById('total').value = total.toFixed(0);
}
</script>


<form >
<input type="checkbox" value="4" onclick="UpdateCost(this);" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have saved the id no of the checkbox  in value . and want total of the weight from other column of table

Comment: Show the code that populates the html form, JS scripts works as long as valid data is passed from the html.